# Maximum command length not reached, yet still exceeded

Tags: bash, matlab, automation, cygwin

I'm having a weird problem when calling a MATLAB function from a (bash) shell script run in CygWin.

This is the problematic command:

```
"$MATLAB_PATH/matlab" -wait -nojvm -nosplash -automation -logfile "$MATLAB_LOGFILE" -r "myFunction $(echo ${FUNCTION_ARGS[@]}); quit;"
```

which, when `echoed` on the bash command line, evaluates to something like the following:

```
/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/MATLAB/R2010a/bin/matlab -wait -nojvm \
    -nosplash -automation -logfile MATLAB_output.txt -r myFunction \
    /path/to/relevant/data/data1.txt /path/to/other/relevant/data/data2.txt \
    <<several more such arguments>>; quit;
```

In total, the length of the command is ~2000 characters, depending a bit on which path the script is called from.

The problem is that my MATLAB function receives only 17 arguments (~1017 characters), while I send it well over 30 arguments.

Other observed behavior:

- When I copy-paste the `echoed` command line into a *regular* MATLAB session (that is, not the automation server), there seems to be no problem and the function executes just fine on all ~30 arguments.
- When I reduce the length of the command line (for example, by removing the `-wait` option), the MATLAB function will suddenly receive 18 arguments, with the last argument a portion of the 18<sup>th</sup> string that I passed in.
- Reducing or increasing the command line length by a few characters in other ways (duplicating slashes in paths, duplicating spaces, etc.) has no effect.
- **EDIT**: The copy-pasted command line length seems to have a maximum length of `1014` characters.

So apparently, somewhere along the tool chain, there is limitation on the maximum length a command can have. I'm not finding anything relevant in the docs of MATLAB, its automation server, bash, or CygWin -- they all have limits, but more in the order of 32K characters, way more than what I'm passing in.

So...I'm at a loss. I'm not sure how to diagnose which tool is causing this...any ideas?

**EDIT:**
Output of `xargs --show-limits`:

```
Your environment variables take up 5556 bytes 
POSIX upper limit on argument length (this system): 24396 
POSIX smallest allowable upper limit on argument length (all systems): 4096 
Maximum length of command we could actually use: 18840 
Size of command buffer we are actually using: 24396
```

Output of `expr $(getconf ARG_MAX) - $(env|wc -c) - $(env|wc -l) \* 4 - 2048`:

```
24098
```

So, as I said, even the smallest of these does not come close to my ~2000 characters.

Comment: Is there anything special about the 17,18,19th arguments or so? Might they include an invalid or unescaped character or some such that the automation server doesn't like? You say you copy and pasted the the echoed version into the non-automation server Matlab – can you also try running it directly (copy/paste can't always be trusted)? Also, it it would be good to confirm that the issue is with the length of the input rather than the number of arguments, so is it possible to test with a bunch of very short arguments?

Comment: @horchler: I put all my data files in the same directory as the MATLAB script, all located in `C:\T`. That call gets the correct amount of arguments into MATLAB. When I then put all data files in the directory `C:\some\super\deeply\nested\directory\just\to\inrease\argument\lengths`, the MATLAB script sees half the arguments and receives a partial string in the last argument. Further experimentation shows that the maximum number of characters the command may have is the not-apparently-special `1014`.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a limit in Matlab's processing of command line. For example, the length of the buffer allocated for the function may be limited to 1014 characters.

In your script, save the function invocation in a script and try to pass the script to Matlab on the command line.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlabwindows.html says:

> matlab -r "statement" starts MATLAB and executes the specified MATLAB statement. If statement is the name of a MATLAB function or script, do not specify the file extension. Any required file must be on the MATLAB search path or in the startup folder.